# Android Studio check out project from Source Control. Project will not compile

Tags: android, svn, android-studio

I have checked out a specific revision of an application to make a minor change.
I tried using Build & Make Module & got 100 compiler errors. Here is a sample:

```
Error:(19, 23) java: package org.apache.http does not exist
Error:(24, 28) java: package org.apache.http.auth does not exist
Error:(29, 30) java: package org.apache.http.client does not exist
Error:(30, 38) java: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist
Error:(32, 35) java: package org.apache.http.conn.params does not exist
```

Obviously Android Studio has made some kind of mistake getting these files, as the version checked out is in live production and working.

There was a dialog I did not understand as I was checking this out.

It asked if I wanted Subversion Working Copy Format 1.6, 1.7 or 1.8. I selected 1.8.

I have Subversion 1.8.14 installed.

Any idea what has gone wrong & how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Did you used third party  SVN  client or Adroid Studio ? May be there was a connection problem with Android Studio.

Comment: I used a command from Android Studio - Checkout a project from Source Control!

Comment: May be getting somewhere: 1. Downloaded httpcomponents-core-4.0.1-bin.zip
2. Copied httpcore-4.0.1.jar to C:\Users\Public\Documents\AndroidStudio\2014B\17718\SVSMobile\libs
3. File > Project Structure. Use + to add the new jar file
4. Recompile. Eliminated a few errors.
5. Downloaded httpcomponents-client-4.0.1-bin.zip
6. Copied httpclient-4.0.1.jar to C:\Users\Public\Documents\AndroidStudio\2014B\17718\SVSMobile\libs
7. File > Project Structure. Use + to add the new jar file
8. Build. Eliminated more errors. Next error says Error:(3, 31) java: package com.google.android.maps doesn't exist